# How to properly handle Realm instance deletion

Tags: android, realm

I have a situation where I want to handle a realm migration in a lazy fashion. Instead of using the Realm Migration api, which the realm developer's state is cumbersome, I want to delete the realm instance and then re-instantiate it only if I need to do a migration. How would I properly handle a this situation such that I only delete and re-instantiate the database ONLY IF it needs to be upgraded?

Say I have a model

```
@RealmClass
public class testmodel extends RealmObject {
    private String foo;
    private int bar;
    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }


    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

and I want to add another string `bazz` into the model with the proper getters and setters.

Currently, I can do this as long as the first time I instantiate realm, I delete it. Like so:

```
    Realm.deleteRealmFile(getApplicationContext());
    realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Now, let's suppose I didn't want to go blowing away my data every time the app starts, but still wanted to do this in the instance when I needed to. I thought a good way would be like this.

```
try{ 
    Log.d(TAG, "started realm creation");
    realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "successfully created realm");
}
catch (RealmException e){ // I tried RealmMigrationNeededException and IllegalState Exception but neither are caught
    Log.d(TAG, "try deleting realm");
    Realm.deleteRealmFile(getApplicationContext());
    realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "deleted realm and remade successfully");
}
```

However, when I try this instead of the exception being caught, my app crashes. 
How would I properly handle a this situation such that I only delete and re-instantiate the database ONLY IF it needs to be upgraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Realm 0.81.0 you can use the new RealmConfiguration object:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
  .schemaVersion(42)
  .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
  .build();
```

This will do exactly what you are looking for.

**Edit:**

JavaDoc is here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html

And you can read more about setup here:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#configuring-a-realm

Comment: Did you choose schema version 42 because it's the answer to everything?

Comment: Yes, in your case you might just want to bump that version whenever you change your model classes :)

Comment: Why isn't this in the documentation? Since when 0.81 has been out?

Comment: @DavidCorsalini most likely a snapshot build, so the documentation isn't out yet.

Comment: It was released to jCenter friday. We are just fixing the last documentation issues, but expect the website to be updated within the next couple of hours. We didn't want to publish this on twitter/google groups before the documentation was online as well.

Comment: Documentation is now online. Post has been updated with links